# c++ compiled in cgi script with curl not working

Tags: c++, apache, curl, cgi, wget

I have a code that is 100% fully functional when compiled in g++ and run in terminal. The code uses wget and curl. When I compile it in to a cgi file and have my html webpage call the script then the curl part of the code does not do anything.

What curl is doing is that it is downloading a webpage which is very critical for my program. I have my apache2 server setup, the cgi file is in cgi-bin folder and everything works except the curl doesnt work in the compiled cgi file.

What are some of the ways to fix this? I have tried many things and none of them seem to work. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely to be either permissions, paths, or environment variables. Try TEMPORARILY relaxing all permissions - maybe making your curl setuid root and adding in code to check return values and error codes from all your system calls. Try outputting all your environment variables in Terminal and in CGI mode and diffing them.

Comment: I did set the permission for my .cgi file via "chmod 755 *.cgi". Is this what you are referring it to?

Comment: Issue fixed by: chmod a+rwx cgi-bin